# Are traces exiting a pad at an angle bad?

Tags: pcb, routing, trace

I have been told in the past that you should always have traces leaving a pad on a straight line.

The reason I was given was that it could create an acid trap. From what I have read this is not really much an issue in modern PCB manufacturing methods.

So is it just a looks/taste/aesthetics thing then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharp corners in PCB traces](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76406/sharp-corners-in-pcb-traces)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to some PCB production service design notes, it can be an issue:

[image]

If the track leaves the pad at a very sharp angle, it may create a "peelable". This refers to narrow pieces of photo resist which can come away during processing and cause shorts. You could also state this as advice not to violate track/track and track/pad design rules even for copper within the same net.

Comment: I'm not clear how a "track-to-track" rule would be applicable unless there's a way of specifying a rule which is only applicable to tracks which are within some number of degrees of being parallel.  Do such rules exist?  Also, is there any way to tell the system that when generating Gerbers it should add copper to the extent necessary to correct issues like your lower example?  Adding a vertical track could correct that problem, but the placement of the vertical track would depend upon the track width.  If the width of the red track changes...

Comment: ...an improperly-placed vertical track could end up creating problems where none would otherwise have existed.

Comment: @supercat: No I don't think so. I think I see what you mean though. When I said track to track I was looking at the top two examples. I don't really have an answer for the bottom example - ie: "what angle is too steep". I wouldn't think a PCB design package would add copper to correct issues. They aren't _that_ smart! They just point out DRC violations. Besides, as you say, it could create more problems.

Comment: Altium10 can catch these very low angle connections through acute angle rule which needs to be defined. I am not sure whether it has anything to do automatic copper fiiling in those areas. It is better to avoid these kinds of connections.